# Как заменить все % из строки, за которыми не следует s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Допустим есть строка:
"Johny was going to %s to buy goods with 20% discount"

Из этой строчки мне нужно заменить процент на %%, но %s оставить без изменений.
Делается это для форматирования строк, по такому типу:

```
a = "Johny was going to %s to buy goods with 20% discount"
print(a % 'store')
```

P.S Я знаю о форматировании вида `f""`, и `string.format(*args, **kwargs)`, в данном случае нужно провести замену % для запроса MySQL, и тут нельзя использовать другие виды форматирования, кроме обычного %

Comment: попробуйте `a.replace("% ", "%%")`

Comment: Пробел после % не всегда бывает. Есть запросы вида "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name like '%test_string%' "
Соответственно могут быть одинарные кавычки, двойные, могут быть скобки и тд, короче обычный replace тут не поможет

Comment: Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями

Comment: Хорошо, а конкретнее?

Comment: А если просто перебрать в цикле всю строку и сделать все, что вы хотите?

Comment: `для запроса MySQL` А может таки не стоит конкатенировать пользовательские данные в запрос? Тогда и проблема не возникнет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наличие `s` после `%` - не очень надежный критерий

```
WHERE column_name like '%some_string%'
```

Но все же если это именно то, что вам нужно

```
print(re.sub('%(?!s)', '%%', '%s%d% %s %d %')) # %s%%d%% %s %%d %%
```

Comment: В моём коде я передаю параметры в строке только с помощью %s, спасибо большое, теперь мне не придётся менять ~300 запросов :)